# Javascript gaJsHost

Tags: javascript

i just want to know the use of this script..

```
 var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");

 document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

i found this on some websites.. :)

and also this one..

```
 var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-1965499-1");

 pageTracker._initData();

 pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

Comment: **`google-analytics.com/ga.js`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) tracker code.

Quote from this link: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55591

> Google Analytics shows you how people
>   found your site, how they explored it,
>   and how you can enhance their visitor
>   experience. With this information, you
>   can improve your website return on
>   investment, increase conversions, and
>   make more money on the web. This guide
>   can help you familiarize yourself with
>   the main features of Google Analytics.

Now, this page suggest the use of your mentioned code:
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55488

Though, this is the old (traditional) method. Google introduced new asynchronous method for adding tracker code.